# gdb "watch" can not variable modified by glibc(read) function?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, glibc

I want to break when`ch`modified.I used`watch ch`in gdb,it does not work.

Something like `ch=1;`will break.Why `read()`not?

Is is right use `watch` command like this. Or the `read()`function is Special?

Sorry for my English, Code say all things.

file 1.c:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
const char *const filename = "/etc/passwd"; 
int main(void) 
{ 
     int fd; 
     int ch; 
     fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY); 
     read(fd, &ch, sizeof(int));  
     printf ("%d\n", ch); 
     close (fd); 
     return 0; 
}
```

`gcc -g 1.c`

debugging:

```
$ gdb a.out  
 GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian 
 Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc. 
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> 
 This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. 
 There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
 and "show warranty" for details. 
 This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu". 
 For bug reporting instructions, please see: 
 <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>... 
 Reading symbols from /home/zodiac1111/tmp/a.out...done. 
 (gdb) b main 
 Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484b5: file 1.c, line 11. 
 (gdb) r 
 Starting program: /home/zodiac1111/tmp/a.out  

 Breakpoint 1, main () at 1.c:11 
 11        fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY); 
 (gdb) watch ch 
 Hardware watchpoint 2: ch 
 (gdb) c 
 Continuing. 
 1953460082 

 Watchpoint 2 deleted because the program has left the block in
 which its expression is valid. 
 __libc_start_main (main=0x80484ac <main>, argc=1, ubp_av=0xbffff4c4,  
     init=0x8048530 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=0x8048520 <__libc_csu_fini>,  
     rtld_fini=0xb7ff0590, stack_end=0xbffff4bc) at libc-start.c:260 
 260    libc-start.c: No such dir...
 (gdb) c 
 Continuing. 
 [Inferior 1 (process 9513) exited normally]
```

Comment: Is ch actually read? Check the result of read.

Comment: `int ch=42;` and `if(read(fd, &ch, sizeof(int))==-1) perror("read:");` I am sure `read()` is succeed.And `ch` is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a normal implementation of `read()`, the write to the memory will be performed directly by the kernel, not by any userspace code. The debugger does not have the mechanisms to put a breakpoint in the kernel, and even if it did, it wouldn't have permission to do so.

Comment: Additionally, the kernel (or even the hardware device driver itself, if file caching is disabled) might be writing to the memory using a different virtual address mapping than the userspace VA.  The x86 debug registers can only monitor virtual addresses, not physical addresses.

Comment: Is where other functions like `read()` can not be `watch`.I want to know all this type functions.Or can you give me some Reference Documents.

Comment: There's no official documentation. Formally, `read` could be a library function that uses the kernel to read into a temporary buffer then `memcpy`'s it to the caller's buffer. This would be inefficient but valid.

Comment: I guess the definition would then be: look into your C library and where it does syscalls in a way that data is written (or read in case you are using awatch) by kernel directly to watched variable this will happen.